# with_subelements when subelement is a dictionary

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible

Say I have the following dict defined in my yml

```
st1: 
  d1:
    f1: fv1
    f2: fv2
    d:
      df1: dfv1
      df2: dfv2
  d2:
    f1: fv3
    f2: fv4
    d:
      df1: dfv3
      df2: dfv4
```

I was able to iterate over the above using with_subelements. like this

with_subelements:

```
-  st1
-  d
```

But I get the following error when I run the playbook.

> FAILED! => {"msg": "the key d should point to a list, got '{u'df1':
>   u'dfv1', u'df2': u'dfv2'}'"}

I am using ansible version 2.4

how can I take only values of dict d into a list to get success with the above playbook.

dictsort or dict2items didn't work for me

Comment: You need to clean that up some, so we have whitespace in your code.

Comment: Thanks Jan!

I know with subelements expects list, but is there any other better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unfortunate that you are stuck with a bad design.  Bad designs result in bad code.  So here's some bad code:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: no
  connection: local

  tasks:

  - set_fact:
      st1_json: "{{ st1 | to_json }}"

  - shell: echo '{{ st1_json }}' | jq '.[].d' | grep ':' | cut -d'"' -f4 | tr '\n' ',' | sed -e 's/^/[/' -e 's/,$/]/' -e 's/,/, /g'
    register: output

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ output.stdout }}"
```

Pretty hideous.  But it gets the desired output:

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "[dfv3, dfv4, dfv1, dfv2]"
}
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Thank you Jack. That will serve the purpose. But my question is still open ended, if a subelement is a dict, how to call it in loops to iterate over the dict values.

Comment: The answer is, you can't.  If you need to do that, then you have to structure the data properly.  This is why data design is so critical.

Answer (score 0):

OK -- I'm not entirely sure what you want for output, but....

I first restructured the yaml file:

```
---
st1: 
  - name: d1
    f1: fv1
    f2: fv2
    d:
      - df1: dfv1
      - df2: dfv2
  - name: d2
    f1: fv3
    f2: fv4
    d:
      - df1: dfv3
      - df2: dfv4
```

Then, the play looks like this:

```
  - debug:
      var: item.1
    with_subelements:
      - "{{ st1 }}"
      - d
```

The output, then, looks like this:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "item.1": {
        "df1": "dfv1"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "item.1": {
        "df2": "dfv2"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "item.1": {
        "df1": "dfv3"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "item.1": {
        "df2": "dfv4"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaponse. I would like to get only a list of all values (not key value pairs) of df1, df2 etc. per each subelement

Comment: I really do not understand what you are expecting.  Do you need to use a particular (df1 or df2) value somewhere?

Comment: For with_subelement, the second one must be a list. However I have a dictionary. 
Ex: I have a user creation playbook, the dictionary is defiled as list of users and their properties like password, uid etc, A user can be member of multiple groups. so the dictionary contains a inner dictionary of group names. if I use with_subelements, I can not iterate over the inner dictionary, as with_subelements expects only a list. So how to get a list of group names to iterate over using with_subelements

Comment: Why can't you restructure the file?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you give us some expected output.  However, you need lists to use `with_subelements`.  If you cannot change the data file, you have to change the playbook.  If you want to see all the `df1` values, then this will do it:

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item.key }}: {{ item.value.d.df1 }}"
    with_dict: "{{ st1 }}"
```

Using your dictionary file, I got this:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "d2: dfv3"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "d1: dfv1"
}
```

Comment: ok. Let me make my question very simple. considering the above playbook, how should I write my debug to only print the values of all the keys in dict d.  I mean something like 

  "msg": [df1, df2, df3, df4]

I have plans to use dict "d" values only [df1, df2] as a list when i am looping over d1, and [df3, df4] as a list when I am looping over d2. 

How to achieve this.

Comment: Also please consider the point that every dict d can have its own number of subelements df1to dfn. That is why i just wanted to grab the values, irrespective of keys.

Comment: Can you change the dictionary?  From what you are saying, d should be an array.

Comment: Unfortunately, the dictionary can not be changed